# Java to c# convertor

Tags: c#, java

looking for a java to c# converter. the project is about 100 classes. what is the best program for this?

Comment: what should i do? i know the converter program won't be perfect.

Comment: examine the c# program, and port it over to java - its tedious, but if you gotta do it, you gotta do it. hope you are getting paid!

Answer (score 5):

The two best options, currently, I believe are Microsoft's [JLCA (Version 3)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1kwtxa08%28VS.80%29.aspx), or [Sharpen](http://developer.db4o.com/Resources/view.aspx/Reference/Sharpen), which runs as an Eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 2):

How about microsoft's Java Language Conversion Assistant

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=46bea47e-d47f-4349-9b4f-904b0a973174&displaylang=en

Answer (score 1):

If your requirement just is *running* the code in .NET, then consider IKVM which allows exactly this.

http://www.ikvm.net/

Also have a look at J# which can compile Java to .NET, but is a bit hard to get hold of.